# Can an invidual sell ArcGIS Pro add-ins at ArcGIS Marketplace?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-pro-sdk, arcgis-market-place

I have an add-in that I would like to sell to ArcGIS pro users. I checked the ESRI website and they have only mentioned ESRI Network partners as eligible providers. Can an indvidual not list products at ArcGIS Marketplace?

> Who are ArcGIS Marketplace program providers?
>
> Providers are Esri Partner Network partners, including Startup and NGO partners and Distributors, in good standing. Contact ArcGIS Marketplace Resource Center for information and to apply to become a provider. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/marketplace/provider/faq.htm#anchor2

Comment: Did you contact the ArcGIS Marketplace Resource Center for information?  What did they tell you?

Comment: Yes I have, they haven't responded yet.